# VIM Regex for Matching Markdown Titles

Tags: regex, vim, markdown

I want to use regex to match markdown titles which start with 1-6 `#` marks, however, in the markdown file, there are python code snippets with comments start with `#`, which could be considered as markdown title wrongly.

Could you find a regex which can parse markdown title corrently? for example I have below markdown snippets:

````
# This is a title

## This is also a title

```python   
import os

# this is a comment, not a title  
os.system("pause")  
```
````

Comment: This cannot be done reliably by a regex. Too many edge cases. But however you may find something which works for *you* in your limited set of input data, for example ignoring python code blocks explicitly...

Comment: If you use the underlined style of markdown titles, _(which imo look better)_ they might be easier to detect.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, this will help you:

```` :%s/^\(\(```python\(.*\n\(^```.*$\)\@!\)\+.*#\)\)/\1**/g ````

then:

`:%s/\#\*\*\(.*$\)/"""\1"""/g`

First one will change the `#` character inside every python snippet to `#**` at the snipped python code.

Last one will change `#**` to a more python general format `""" comment """`

> LIMITATIONS: only works for only one comment by snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Another general way to do that is:

````
:%s/\(```python\_.\{-}```\)\|^\(\W\+\)\@<!/**\1
````

Then:

```
:%s/^\#\(.*\)/"\1"
```

Finally:

```
%s/^\**//g
```

Example, before:

````
# This is a title

## This is also a title

```python   
import os

# this is a comment, not a title  os.system("pause")  
```
# This is a title

## This is also a title

```python   
import os

# this is a comment, not a title  os.system("pause")

print("Blah blah")  

# this is another comment  
```
````

After:

````
# This is a title

## This is also a title

```python   
import os

" this is a comment, not a title  os.system("pause")  "
```
# This is a title

## This is also a title

```python   
import os

" this is a comment, not a title  os.system("pause")"

print("Blah blah")  

" this is another comment  "
```
````

Another simpler way is:

````
:%s/\(```\_.\{-}```\n\)\zs\|#\+\( .*\)/"\2 "/g
````